# How to exclude certain folders from Visual Studio 2012 detected changes list?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, team-explorer

In Visual Studio 2012 / Team Explorer / Pending Changes there is a link to list of files with detected changes inside the solution.

How can I make Visual Studio NOT to detect pending changes in `_ReSharper.*` and `Packages` folders?

[image]

Comment: Don't add the `_Resharper.*` and `Packages` to your solution...

Comment: @nemesv, of cause these folders are not included into .sln file, but still they are on the disk in a solution folder.

Comment: Just to clarify:  these are getting automatically added to the *Excluded Changes* list, correct?  And you don't even want to see them there?  Or before your screenshot, have you already manually excluded them?

Answer (score 6):

You can manually add a .tfignore file to your solution to ignore specific files, extensions or folders. The items defined in that file will not be considered as a change. If you click on the 'detected changes' you can also ignore items from within Visual studio (by right-clicking a selected item).

In case of resharper you can choose to put the cache files in the system temp folder. That way you don't have to exclude them from source control:

<strike>http://www.splatto.net/portfolio/blog/post/2009/06/29/Removing-Resharper-Cache-Directories-in-Project-Solution-Folder.aspx</strike>

Update: The above link no longer resolves, but information on configuring your Cache location in ReSharper is available in the [Resharper Help Center](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Configuring_Caches_Location.html)

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to ignore all the "_Resharper.*" and "Packages" folders from my workspace:

1. Choose to ignore any folder. This will cause the .tfignore file to be create at the root level of you workspace (if it did not already exist) and appear in the "Included Changes" area.
2. Double click on the .tfignore file in your "Included Changes". This should open it up for editing.
3. Remove whatever folder you added at step 1, then add "_ReSharper.*" and "Packages" on separate lines. Save the file.

When you restart Visual Studio, you should now find that all the ReSharper and Packages folders are ignored from the detected changes.