# exclude folders in Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools

Tags: tfs

I have included a folder with several sub folders in TFS, which is not a VS solution. Basically it is a bunch of XML files mainly, which are manipulated via some GUI. How can I exclude certain subfolders from check-in while check-in the 'solution'/folder?

Comment: Confusing: from what *action* you want exclusion?

Comment: sorry - in svn speak from commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually include or exclude files from a check-in: the UI is a bit different if you are using the 2012 TFS client (Team Explorer) or an older version. It is described at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx).

On the [Customize which files are ignored by version control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#tfignore) section, you see a way to 'permanently' exclude folders or file types from a check-in.

Comment: I do not want to exclude certain file extension, I want to exclude certain folders (e.g. containing cache files)

Comment: It works for folders also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329362/how-to-exclude-certain-folders-from-visual-studio-2012-detected-changes-list