# Missing the "Detect changes" link in visual studio 2012 team explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm was looking for the proper way to exclude folders/files from team foundation server (2012) using visual studio 2012. I found:
[how-to-exclude-certain-folders-from-visual-studio-2012-detected-changes-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329362/how-to-exclude-certain-folders-from-visual-studio-2012-detected-changes-list) on stackoverflow. However the shown detect changes link is missing in my team explorer[image: missing link picture]. There should be a detect changes link in the red circle as compared to the screenshot in the linked question

I could not comment on the original question to ask this, so I made a new one. Does anyone know where the detected changes link went. (and yes the project had pending changes when I tested)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a verb ("detect changes"), it's a noun:  "detected changes".  Which are changes that were found on the filesystem by watching your activity, but will not be included in the checkin.

This occurs when you use a [*local workspace*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278842/tfs-workspaces-across-vs-2010-and-2012).  You will not see it if you are using a server workspace, since you must pend changes manually.

If you have changes that were made on the filesystem that were not pended, and you would like to detect them, run `tfpt online` from the [TFS Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35775).  Or convert to a local workspace, and find them in the detected changes tab.

Comment: Sorry for the spelling/copy text error, but English is not my native language and I did not notice it. We only recently (I know late) migrated the tfs from 2008 to a newer version and I did not know about the local workspace. Could you also tell how to get vs2012 to ignore the nuget package folder (or any other) on check-in?

Comment: Sorry if I came across as overly pedantic - I pointed out the difference only because there *is* a "detect changes" command in other areas of TFS clients and I wanted to make sure that wasn't the expectation.  To ignore nuget package folders, you should be able to set up a `.tfignore` file:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx

Comment: No worries Edward, I'm not insulted. It's better to mention it because I might not get any assistance when the question will not be seen or understood, just because I made a error copying the function name. But things like verb and noun and exact English spelling rules are beyond me. I'm happy if understood. Thank you for answering.